# Strange typecast behavior

Tags: c, casting

I have this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int func(unsigned int *a) {
  printf("(func) Value: %d\n", *a);
}

int main() {
  unsigned char a = 255;

  printf("Value: %d\n", a);
  printf("Bytes: %d %d %d %d\n\n", *&a, *(&a + 1), *(&a + 2), *(&a + 3));

  func((unsigned int *) &a);

  return 0;
}
```

I have the output of this program:

```c
Value: 255
Bytes: 255 0 22 234

(func) Value: -367656705
```

Why i have negative func value, though the type is unsigned int?

Comment: Because you used `%d` instead of `%u`.

Comment: Exactly... I'm so inconsiderate. Thanks!

Comment: Undefined behavior - you are accessing memory that do not belong to any defined variable

Comment: This program if rife with undefined behavior.  You are accessing random values on the stack with things like `*(&a + 1)`.  You're casting the address of an `unsigned char` to `unsigned int *` and then attempting to dereference the result, which is again undefined behavior and could easily result in an alignment exception.

Comment: It's just a test program, and question wasn't about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why i have negative func value, though the type is unsigned int?

```
int func(unsigned int *a) {
  printf("(func) Value: %d\n", *a);
  //                    ^^
}
```

Because `%d` does not match type of `*a`

Answer (score 0):

Because sizeof(unsigned char) and sizeof(unsigned int) are different and can also be platform dependent.  For example, unsigned char can be 1 byte.  unsigned int can be 4 bytes.  When you do your pointer arithmetic, you are possibly looking at other things in the stack frame.  C provides you lots of rope to hang yourself with.